# INSERTing very long string in an SQL query - ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, string, insert, long-integer

The problem is that whenever I input a big-ass text in the form of my php page and try to `INSERT` it through a SQL query into the database, it gives me an error like this:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'sample title', 'spent the long months of the rainy season shut up in a small room th' at line 1"

The query is this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `d` (`user_id`, `title`, `message`) VALUES ($user_id, '$topic', '$message')";
```

The interesting thing is that it gives me no error when I manually insert the values and run the query in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prepared statements:

```
$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db.prepare("INSERT INTO `d` (`user_id`, `title`, `message`) VALUES ($user_id, :topic, :message)");
// I'm assuming that title is a VARCHAR(50) and message is a VARCHAR(500)
$stmt->bindParam(":topic", $topic, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
$stmt->bindParam(":message", $topic, PDO::PARAM_STR, 500);
$stmt->execute();
```

This places the job of escaping / properly passing data squarely in the hands of the database engine - which is where it belongs.  Avoid building SQL strings from user input wherever you can and you'll avoid many potential SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

I bet there are single quotes ( ' ) in the string. Escape `$topic` before using it in your INSERT.